# Boxplot disappears when adjusting y lim

Tags: r, boxplot, axis-labels

I want my boxplot to have the y axis to go from 0 to 20,000 , but when I add the argument `ylim = c(0,20000)`, my entire boxplot disappears.
Here is my code:

```
bp.gender <- boxplot(
    music_data.frame$Income ~ music_data.frame$Gender, 
    xlab = "Gender", 
    ylab = "Income", 
    main = "Income distribution for Gender", 
    col = "red", 
    ylim = c(0,20000)
```

Comment: Since we do not have your data, we cannot run your code and see the results that you got.  Please add your data by pasting in the results of `dput(music_data.frame)`

Comment: based on your code, you are missing a bracket after the ``ylim()`` call.